# Worklight 6.1 : Issue in worklight connection with BB old 6 /7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am using worklight 6.2 and build a blackberry 6 /7 sample app but i am facing connection issue.

Because of connection issue i am not able to call adapter and every time i am getting failure as response from adapter.

My code snippet is given below

config.xml

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" version="1.0" rim:backButton="exit">  
    <name>bb67</name>  
    <description>bb67</description>  
    <author email="application author's e-mail">application's author</author>  
    <feature id="worklightFeature" required="false" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.ui.menu" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke.BrowserArguments" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.identity" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.app" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.app.event" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <access subdomains="true" uri="*"/>  
    <content src="www/skinLoader.html"/>  
    <icon rim:hover="false" src="icon.png"/>  
    <rim:loadingScreen backgroundImage="" foregroundImage="splash.png" onLocalPageLoad="false" onFirstLaunch="true"/> 
</widget>
```

index,html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>bb67</title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
            <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
        <link href="worklight/worklight.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script>
        // Define WL namespace.
        var WL = WL ? WL : {};
        /**
         * WLClient configuration variables.
         * Values are injected by the deployer that packs the gadget.
         */
         WL.StaticAppProps = {
   "APP_DISPLAY_NAME": "bb67",
   "APP_ID": "bb67",
   "APP_SERVICES_URL": "http:\/\/192.168.0.222:10080\/bb67\/apps\/services\/",
   "APP_VERSION": "1.0",
   "ENVIRONMENT": "blackberry",
   "LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE": "embedded",
   "WORKLIGHT_PLATFORM_VERSION": "6.2.0.01.20141027-1531",
   "WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL": "http:\/\/192.168.0.222:10080\/bb67\/apps\/services\/api\/bb67\/blackberry\/"
};
</script>
        <script src="worklight/wljq.js"></script>
        <script src="worklight/worklight.js"></script>
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
    </head>
    <body style="display: none;">
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            Hello Worklight<input onclick="msiteCall()" type="button" value="Call Adapter">
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
/* JavaScript content from js/main.js in folder common */
function wlCommonInit(){
    /*
     * Use of WL.Client.connect() API before any connectivity to a Worklight Server is required. 
     * This API should be called only once, before any other WL.Client methods that communicate with the Worklight Server.
     * Don't forget to specify and implement onSuccess and onFailure callback functions for WL.Client.connect(), e.g:
     *    
     *    WL.Client.connect({
     *          onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
     *          onFailure: onConnectFailure
     *    });
     *     
     */

    // Common initialization code goes here
      WL.Client.connect({
                onSuccess: function onConnectSuccess(res){
                        alert('Connection Success '+res);
                },
                onFailure: function onConnectFailure(res){
                        alert('Connection Failure '+res);
                }
         });
}

/* JavaScript content from js/main.js in folder blackberry */
// This method is invoked after loading the main HTML and successful initialization of the Worklight runtime.
function wlEnvInit(){
    wlCommonInit();
    // Environment initialization code goes here
}
var timeout = 30000;
function msiteCall(){
    alert('Inside call');

    var invocationData = {
            adapter : "msiteAdap",
            procedure : "getStories",
            parameters : [],
            compressResponse : true
    };
    //WL.Logger.debug('invoke msg  '+invocationData, '');
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess : function succ(){alert("Success...");},
        onFailure : function fail(){alert("Failure...");},              

    });
}
```

Please suggest if anything is missing. I am using webworks for building project.
I using below command for building cod file.

```
bbwp C:\myapp\myarchive.zip -d -o C:\myapp\output
```

And below is the generated structure from worklight project.

[image]

Please suggest if there any correct document with webwork project in worklight.

Comment: Mention what is the "connection issue" - client logs and servers logs

Comment: It is working on worklight preview but when i run this in device it is giving connection issue.

Comment: if worklight server is not getting connecting then how will fetch logs from server.

Comment: Please find below link for sample code http://50.17.252.160/Sample/BBOldSample.zip  , in this worklight connection is not workling. If u can check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64287/discussion-between-vishal-g-and-idan-adar).

Comment: have you managed to overcome this problem?

Comment: Yes, In device(BB7 version) it is working f9 now but not able to manage same in simulator. In simulator same issue is persist.

Comment: Can you provide an update to this question?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it was written that this has been resolved for when running the application in a physical device. This device is connected by WiFi to the same network the server is running in.

The remaining problem is when running the application in the BlackBerry Simulator, which is actually running inside VMWare Fusion.

If that VM is unable to reach your local network then the application running inside it will also fail connecting to the server.

Suggestions:

- Go through the VM settings and make sure it is correctly setup to access your local network
- You can check this by opening a browser inside it and see if you are able to access the Worklight Console of the server